# Apparent conflict when using hyperref and pdfcomment together

Tags: hyperref, errors, warnings, pdfcomment

There appears to be a conflict with using the `hyperref` package and `pdfcomment`. Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get a warning message from `hyprerref` related to `pdftex` being called twice and that it changes nothing. I don't really like to leave a document with warning messages on the compilation. If I change the order of the packages, then there is an outright error. The error relates the the `hidelinks` option, though I think it is probably a problem with other options too. If I remove the option, then the code will compile without error or warning (provided that `pdfcomment` is loaded first.)

Any ideas about a resolution for this: should I be passing a bug report onto either of these two parties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you need to be worried about this: what you're getting is a Warning message, not an Error message:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdftex' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line [xx].
```

This warning message is generated by LaTeX while it's setting up the `pdfcomment` package, which (among others) also loads the `hyperref` package.

Furthermore, because `pdfcomment` loads the `hyperref` package anyway, you needn't even load `hyperref` separately. After loading the `pdfcomment` package, just issue the command `\hypersetup{hidelinks,<any other options>}`.

Finally, it may be worth noting that `hyperref` checks which engine is compiling the document; if it's "pdftex", it automatically enables the `pdftex` option for you -- no need for you to specify it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I basically don't like warning messages... I'm a kind of neat freak. this was helpful, I didn't know about the `\hypersetup` command, so the solution is still kind of elegant. One should make sure that the `pdfcomment` package is loaded in the same place as `hyperref` (relative to other packages) or else some odd warning messages can come up.