# Strange side effect between amsmath, hyperref and cleveref

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, cleveref, pdfcomment

This issue seems rather exotic, but I encountered it in a medium-sized document, and it took me a while to indentify which particular combination of packages was responsible.

When I load `amsmath`, `cleveref` and `hyperref` (*implicitly* via `pdfcomment`), `ref`/`autoref` to an equation no longer work, i.e., LaTeX throws an `Reference ... on page 1 undefined` error.
See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%% Hyperlinks
%\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%% implicitly loads `hyperref`
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
Etwas Fülltext, bevor die Gleichung kommt:
\begin{equation}
E_\mathrm{kin} = \frac{m}{2} v^2 \label{eq:kinErg}
\end{equation}
Jemand fand heraus, dass \autoref{eq:kinErg} gilt.

\end{document}
```

If I include `hyperref` *explicitly*, then everything works except I get [this warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42525). Not a deal breaker, but I'd prefer to avoid it and just use `hypersetup` for the additional options for `hyperref`.

Also, if I omit `amsmath`, everything works, too. I suppose that each package partially overwrites each other's settings...

If this is a bug, then where should I report it?

Comment: You're loading packages in the wrong order. Each package manipulates at least one aspect of the `\label-\ref` system, so the correct order of loading is crucial here: `amsmath` → `hyperref` → `cleveref`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `cleveref` **always** after `hyperref` as one of the few exception where packages should be loaded after `hyperref`!

Doing it in the wrong order, the `counter` information is overwritten and `\autoref` can't get grip of the counter i.e. the label is 'undefined', leading to wrong references or `??` as output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%% Hyperlinks
%\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
%% implicitly loads `hyperref`
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}
Etwas Fülltext, bevor die Gleichung kommt:
\begin{equation}
  E_\mathrm{kin} = \frac{m}{2} v^2 \label{eq:kinErg}
\end{equation}
Jemand fand heraus, dass \autoref{eq:kinErg} gilt.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no advantage of `\autoref` here